# 4x4 board hopping with 4 blue, 5 red and 7 green

Tags: probability

A 4-by-4 square board is divided into 16 unit squares. Each unit square is one solid color: 4 are blue, 5 are red and 7 are green. A bug randomly hops about the board. Each hop can be any distance and always takes him to a square that is different in color than the unit square he just hopped from. If the bug starts on a red square, what is the probability that its third hop lands him on a red square? Express your answer as a common fraction.

I draw the tree structure for this:

R - 4B - 7G - 5R.
R - 4B - 7G - 4B.
R - 4B - 5R - 4B.
R - 4B - 5R - 7G.

R - 7G - 4B - 5R.
R - 7G - 4B - 7G.
R - 7G - 5R - 4B.
R - 7G - 5R - 7G.

so probability to land on red is 280/1193. However the provided answer is 70/297. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The probability of $R\to B\to G\to R$ is
$$P(B|R)\cdot P(G|B)\cdot P(R|G)=\frac{4}{4+7}\cdot\frac{7}{7+5}\cdot\frac{5}{5+4}=\frac{35}{297}.$$
Similarly, the probability of $R\to G\to B\to R$ is
$$P(G|R)\cdot P(B|G)\cdot P(R|B)=\frac{7}{7+4}\cdot\frac{4}{4+5}\cdot\frac{5}{5+7}=\frac{35}{297}.$$
The sum is $70/297$.

Comment: (4+7)(7+5)(5+4)=4x7x5+4x7x4+4x5x5+4x5x4+7x7x5+7x7x4+7x5x5+7x5x4=1188 which is essentially all the possible path for 3 hops; However if one draw out the tree the total number of path count is: 4x7x4+4x7x5+4x5x4+4x5x7+7x4x5+7x4x7+7x5x4+7x5x7=1193; if you look at the real path tree, it's not possible to come up with 4x5x5 or 7x5x5. I can't tell where it went different along the way, but something is still not quite right here; the numbers don't square up as they should be

Comment: You have correctly enumerated the paths, but they are not equally likely, so your approach does not yield the correct results.  It might be a useful exercise for you to compute the other 6 probabilities by using the approach shown in the supplied answers and verify that all 8 add up to 1, as they must.

Answer (score 0):

Here are favorable sequences: $$R - G - B - R$$ $$R - B - G - R$$
The probability of a first sequence is $\frac{7}{11}\frac{4}{9}\frac{5}{12}$. The probability of the second sequence is $\frac{4}{11}\frac{7}{12}\frac{5}{9}$, so exactly the same. We, therefore, can compute the probability of interest as $2*\frac{7}{11}\frac{4}{9}\frac{5}{12} = 2*\frac{7}{11}\frac{1}{9}\frac{5}{3} = \frac{70}{297}$. Notice that denominators are different from 16 - this is to take into account the impossibility of hopping to the same color.